# How to play video in Android from video link

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming

How I can to play video in Android by passing whatever video link (for example - "https://youtu.be/SiD77g9KfhA" or it can be another video link from another media portal). I tried to do this,but i am getting an error.

My code

```
try {
                if (!mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
                    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    mVideoView.pause();
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){

            }
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    mVideoView.start();
                }
            });
```

Error.

[image]

Comment: You should set direct link to video (not link for page with video)

Comment: You shold provide the stacktrace, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: @DeKaNszn link which i added is not an direct link to video?

Comment: @Vaniusha no, direct link (for example) should be as `http://example.com/video.mp4`

Comment: @DeKaNszn so how i can get this direct link from whatever youtube video?(or another media portal)

Answer (score 0):

what you have given is page url not the video url this one worked me try this url.

http://tamilhd.in/load/Tamil%20Movies%20Trailers/2017%20Tamil%20Movies%20Trailers/Baahubali%202%20Trailer/320x240/Baahubali%202%20Trailer.mp4

Comment: Yes,now its working. But how I can get direct link like this,for example from whatever video in youtube?

Comment: keepvid.com here you can get direct URLs. Also u can get direct url by downloading videos from mobile sites in desktop or laptop. For youtube you can right click on the video and select copy video url.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code `snippet`. I used this code in my app to play video in `landscape` mode.

```
package xyz.abc.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FullVideo extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;
    private int position = 0;
    String videoUrl, imageUrl, cid;

     private MediaController mediaControls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_video);

        videoUrl = "https://youtu.be/SiD77g9KfhA"

        if (mediaControls == null) {
            mediaControls = new MediaController(FullVideo.this);
        }

        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FullVideo.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Streaming video, please wait.");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {

            mediaControls.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediaControls);
            // mediaControls.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.requestFocus();
                videoview.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    videoview.start();                  
                } else {
                    videoview.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
            finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("Position", videoview.getCurrentPosition());
        videoview.pause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        videoview.seekTo(position);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I'm trying run my app with your code

Comment: doesnt work, i tried it on url "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" as well as the one you have already written

Comment: An Error occurred, try again later.